# Unable to resolve the error: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return-type

Getting the error: "control reaches end of non-void function" and unable to resolve it

The full code is available at: [the actual program](http://inls.ucsd.edu/~fisher/Fractals/enc.c)

```
 /* ************************************************************** */
 /* free memory allocated in the list structure the_domain         */
 /* ************************************************************** */
 list_free(node)
 struct classified_domain *node;
{
    if (node->next != NULL)
    list_free(node->next);
    free(node);

}
```

Comment: how old is this code...

Comment: eyeball parser broken.

Comment: oh that is K&R... ugh, is that legal anymore?

Comment: I did read the answers to similar questions, but didn't work - it gave me a new error `expected error`

Comment: @GradyPlayer - the default compiler on HPUX 11 is/was K&R cc.  You had to pay extra to get a modern compiler.  FWIW.

Comment: @JoshCaswell its there in the description

Comment: @JoshCaswell i'm getting the same error for the all four and this is the only error in the whole program.

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand that it was the same message. That does strongly suggest that the solution will be the same, however.

Answer (score 0):

list_free() is implied to return an int.  By default if a function has no data type your compiler is assuming it returns an int.   I do not remember if K&R supports the void datatype, but I don't think it does.

Try:

```
 list_free(node)
 struct classified_domain *node;
{
    if (node->next != NULL)
    list_free(node->next);
    free(node);
    return 1;    
}
```

Edit: forgot to add `int list_free(node)`.  It will be less confusing that way.  Up to you.